# Can't redirect because of error "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String."

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, gridview

I'm very new to this so I don't understand what is wrong here.

I created button in the column of the gridview with event to redirect to another web form with passing gridview row items parameters. I get this error 
`Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.`

```
protected void gvAccommodations_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Open")
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("~/Rooms.aspx?Id=" + Id);
    }
}


<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
</asp:BoundField>          
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOdaberi" runat="server" Text="Odaberi" 
                       CommandName="Open" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: ... `Id.ToString()`. Actually, the error message clearly states what is the problem.

Comment: *Where* is that error?

Comment: Do you get the error when the GridView is rendered? When the page loads?

Comment: I get the error when I click the button to go to the new web form

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace or the line of code where the error actually occurs?

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/wtsym29q9/) this is what I get

Answer (score 0):

You can't join an integer onto a string - you have to convert it to a string first using ToString.

So use this line:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Rooms.aspx?Id=" + Id.ToString());
```

Comment: Actually `.ToString()` will be inferred by the compiler because you're adding it to a string, so it should not be necessary. I don't think that's the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void gvAccommodations_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();
if (e.CommandName == "Open")
{
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    Response.Redirect("~/Rooms.aspx?Id=" id);
}
}
```